# Working with edit form inside bootstrap modal dialog using php

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, sql-update

So basically I have a table of employee basic information. It already has values which is retrieved from mysql database. [employee basic information table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RodnW.png). So as you can see on the table, it has an edit button at the top right corner. Once clicked, modal dialog will show up. [edit basic information modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vweG.png).

My problem is I don't know how to update the records on the basic information table once the user filled-out the fields on the edit form and click on the save button.

What I want to happen is when the user clicked on the save button on the modal dialog, it will automatically change the existing data on the table to an updated one, no need for reloading the page.

So meaning, it requires an ajax or jquery for updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page which I don't have any idea how it works.

Here's my code for the table:

```
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Edit</button>
<div class="clear text-primary bold"><i class="fa fa-user text-primary"></i> Basic Information    </div> 
<br>
<section class="padder-v">
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>   
      <tr>
        <th>
          <strong> Employee ID</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['emp_code']; ?></p>
        </td>

        <th>
          <strong> Birthdate</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['birthdate']; ?></p>
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <strong> Last Name</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['lname']; ?></p>
        </td>

        <th>
          <strong> Gender</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['gender']; ?></p>
        </td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <strong> First Name</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?></p>
        </td>

        <th>
          <strong> Marital Status</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['status']; ?></p>
        </td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <strong>Middle Name</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['mname']; ?></p>
        </td>
        <th>
          <strong> Active</strong>
        </th>
        <td>
          <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $_SESSION['active']; ?></p>
        </td>    
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Code for php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['emp_fname'];
    $middlename = $_POST['emp_mname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['emp_lname'];
    $birthdate = $_POST['emp_bday'];
    $gender = $_POST['emp_gender'];
    $maritalstatus = $_POST['emp_maritalstatus'];

    $query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tbl_employee SET emp_fname = '$firstname', 
                                                emp_mname = '$middlename', 
                                                emp_lname = '$lastname', 
                                                emp_bday = '$birthdate', 
                                                emp_gender = '$gender',
                                                emp_maritalstatus = '$maritalstatus',
                                                WHERE emp_id = '$emp_code'");
    if($query){
?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> You Added a New Borrower!
</div>
<?php } else{ ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Danger!</strong> Something's wrong with the Process! 
</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Code for modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">  <i class="fa fa-user text-primary"></i> Basic Information</h4>
  </div>     
    <div class="modal-body">         
                <form method="post" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emp_fname">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp_fname" name="emp_fname" value ="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>" required>
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emp_bday">Birthdate </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp_bday" name="emp_bday"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['birthdate']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            <!--- -->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="emp_mname">Middle Name </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp_mname" name="emp_mname"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['mname']; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emp_gender">Gender</label><br>
                                       <select class="form-control" name="emp_gender">
                                          <option>Male</option>
                                          <option>Female</option>
                                       </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            <!--- -->                            
                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="emp_lname">Last Name </label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp_lname" name="emp_lname"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lname']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="emp_maritalstatus">Marital Status</label><br>
                                             <select class="form-control" name="emp_maritalstatus">
                                                <option>Single</option>
                                                <option>Married</option>
                                                <option>Divorced</option>
                                                <option>Separated</option>
                                                <option>Widowed</option>
                                             </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            <!--- -->                               
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button id = "submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                 </form>
           </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: for starting, you need to add `hidden` input with value `<?php echo $_SESSION['emp_code']; ?>` and post it along with other form values, because in PHP file, update query will be failing because there are no `$emp_code` value `WHERE emp_id = '$emp_code'`

Comment: check my answer it may work for you

Answer (score 1):

The `$emp_code` is not found when you post data from modal.  Your query will be failing because there are no `$emp_code` value `WHERE emp_id = '$emp_code'`

So you need to add hidden input with value `<?php echo $_SESSION['emp_code']; ?>` and post it along with other form values, because in PHP file.

**ADD in Modal form**

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="emp_code" name="emp_code" value ="<?php echo $_SESSION['emp_code']; ?>" >
```

**ADD in PHP file**

```
$emp_code = $_POST['emp_code'];
```

**UPDATE**

The other Issue is in your query, There is extra comma after **`emp_maritalstatus = '$maritalstatus',`** so it will get error in updating.

**I have update query**

```
 $query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tbl_employee SET emp_fname = '$firstname', 
                                                emp_mname = '$middlename', 
                                                emp_lname = '$lastname', 
                                                emp_bday = '$birthdate', 
                                                emp_gender = '$gender',
                                                emp_maritalstatus = '$maritalstatus'
                                                WHERE emp_id = '$emp_code'");
```

Comment: actually there is. I didn't include it in the question                                                        <?php 
session_start();
require_once '../scripts/connect.php';
$emp_code = $_SESSION['emp_code'];
$emp_pos = $_SESSION['emp_pos'];
$tbl_name = $_SESSION['tbl_name'];